# Wired, 1.0 speaker with good bass

Tags: speakers

I am looking for a speaker for my smartphone. But I don't need it to be portable nor wireless (bluetooth) because I can plug it to the grid and I can connect it to the phone with a regular TRS cable. I just need it to have a good bass. Or a decent bass. I need the speaker to be significantly better than the speaker of my phone.

I would like to buy something that's not more expensive than $50 or maximum $60

I noticed the Logitech Z50 1.0 Speaker (out of stock at NewEgg). Some vendors (like for example NewEgg) don't even have the 1.0 in the list of speakers configuration - you can chose from 2.0, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1 etc - but there is no option to chose the 1.0 speakers. Also the searching reviews for 1.0 speakers finds mostly reviews about bluetooth speakers. It doesn't look extremely easy to find alternatives for a plain 1.0 speaker

Comment: You don't need it to be wireless, but is there a reason it can't be wireless?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths - Well, I guess the signal is better on a wire than on wireless (faster, bigger bandwidth, no chokes). But if a wireless speaker has a decent quality, that's good enough for me. By the way, is there any wireless speaker that can also be connected by (TRS) cable?